# Multiple string manipulation not working

Tags: c, string

I am trying to define multiple strings in a double array such that 
values[0][]="something", values[1][]="something else...
I then want to pad the length of each string so that they are 128 characters.
Finally, I want to split the 128 string into 4-char strings and write them 4 by 4 (so 32 writes). I know I have several problems but can anyone assist?

I found the problem. Here is my code and it does what I want. Thanks to all the suggestions.

```
for(k=0;k<inputs;k++){//do for all inputs
   flag = 0;
   int len = strlen(values[k]);
   int padded_len = 127;
   int i;
   //pad inputs
   for(i = 0; i < padded_len-len; i++){
               strcat(values[k], "0");
   }

   for (off = 0; off < 128; off += 4){
        strncpy(temp[k], values[k]+off, 4);
        temp[k] = '\0';

        temp_int = *((uint32 *) &values[k][off]);

        if(flag==0){
        //write to HW regy
        flag=1;
        }
        else{
        //write to HW regx
        flag=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `const char values`!!!!!

Comment: One problem right off the top is modifying a `const` string. Lose the `const` qualifier on your global `values` if you plan on writing to that stack of strings (which you apparently do since you `strcat(values, "0")`).

Comment: You run out of the buffer when adding the string up to 128 characters... where is the trailing \0 supposed to be?

Comment: and what should `strncpy(temp[k], ...`  mean? why to write to the k-th character? It wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, looks like you have an error with the padding section when referencing our values[] array, so it should be:

```
   //pad inputs
   for(i = 0; i < padded_len-len; i++){
               strcat(values[k], "0");
   }
```

EDIT:

Also, you need to increase the size of your string array to include room for the null terminator:

```
... char values[3][129]...
```

Comment: I made those changes. i edited the question to show the warnings.